# Updating selected index value of dynamically created dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a survey application and there is a dynamic dropdownlist controller .In summary part of the survey (just before submitting the results) , I want to display same dropdownlist option selected which is selected on previous page's dropdownlist.

It works first time load but when I go back and change the option and come back to the summary page , I still see the old option selected in dropdownlist . `alert(getdropdata);`dispalys updated selection but dropdownlist itself doesn't display updated selection

```
$("#mydropdown2").empty();

var getdropdata=sessionStorage.getItem("gettingData");

questionAnswerElement.append('<select style="width:160px;margin-top: 1px;"  id="mydropdown2"  runat="server" disabled>'
    + '<option value="' + question.options1 + '">' + question.options1 + '</option>'
    + '<option value="' + question.options2 + '">' + question.options2 + '</option>'
    + '<option value="' + question.options3 + '">' + question.options3 + '</option>'
    + '<option value="' + question.options4 + '">' + question.options4 + '</option></select>');
alert(getdropdata);

document.getElementById("mydropdown2").selectedIndex = getdropdata;
```

Comment: Try to use `$("#mydropdown2").val(getdropdata);` or `$('#mydropdown2 option')[getdropdata].selected = true;` instead .

Answer (score 0):

`sessionStorage` has an expiration date. Why not use `localStorage` which doesn't expire?

Comment: I can also use it though but the issue seems different. after the first process , dropdownlist doesn't reflect updated results